# Creating unit test project in rider adds a lot of linked files

Tags: rider, jetbrains-rider

When I create a unit test project in Rider it adds a lot of linked files to the directory:

[image]

Is this normal?

I have looked in both the .csproj & .sln and can't see why it is linking files from nuget package cache to project (these files are not in project folder, they are linked directly from location in package cache).

Where are these links specified?

Comment: They came from msbuild targets. When you enable "show all files" mode Rider shows whole project content

Comment: Does this also happen for newer platforms, e. g. .NET 6.0? Because .NET Core 2.1 has been deprecated quite some time ago - maybe you're the victim of a bug...